# Issue in Radios Button validation in magento2

Tags: magento2

Requried field validation is not working.

```
$baseFieldset->addField('division', 'radios', array(
          'label'     => ('Division'),
          'name'      => 'division',    
          'class' => 'validate-one-required-by-name',         
          'required' => true,                 
          'values' => array(
                            array('value'=>'MV','label'=>'MV'),
                            array('value'=>'AV','label'=>'AV'),
                            array('value'=>'Both','label'=>'Both'),
                       ),
          'disabled' => false
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, you have to change **`radios to radio`** inside your code,

```
$baseFieldset->addField('division', 'radio', array(
          'label'     => ('Division'),
          'name'      => 'division',    
          'class' => 'validate-one-required-by-name',         
          'required' => true,                 
          'values' => array(
                            array('value'=>'MV','label'=>'MV'),
                            array('value'=>'AV','label'=>'AV'),
                            array('value'=>'Both','label'=>'Both'),
                       ),
          'disabled' => false
        ));
```

Comment: It is not working. I am asking magento 2. You tell the magento 1